# Trouble using HashMap containing Objects

Tags: java, dictionary, oop, hashmap, jvm

Please pardon my bad English

I am trying to create a HashMap with a String as a key, and an Object as parameter, which I want to initialise each time the program runs so that its added to a new key in the HashMap.

The problem is, that not all values are returned, and namely the second, gives back a weird output.

```
package javaex1;
import java.util.*;

public class Javaex1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Person obj = new Person("Eminem", "Male");
    HashMap<String, Person> MapPerson = new HashMap<String, Person>();
    MapPerson.put("Eminem", obj);

    System.out.println(MapPerson);
  }    
}
```

The object

```
package javaex1;


public class Person {


String Name;
String Gender;


public Person (String name, String Gend) {

    this.Name = name;
    this.Gender = Gend;
}    


public String getName() {
    return Name;
}

public String getGender() {
    return Gender;
}


}
```

Any help or hint is greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance for your time!

The expected results should be "Eminem Male". Instead what I get is this:

```
{Eminem=javaex1.Person@2a139a55}
```

Comment: you're getting hashcode values of object. override your toString method or try     System.out.println(MapPerson.collect());

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you are trying to print an Object, An Object when printed gives the default toString implementaion of Object class , which is shown below

// implementation of toString in Object class

```
 public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

This is what you can see in your current output .

You should ovverride toString method in Person class like this.

```
    public String toString() {
    return this.Name + " " + this.Gender; 
}
```

So that it returns the name and gender

Answer (score 1):

You should override `toString` method in `Person` class. Like that:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.Name + " " + this.Gender;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You're printing the `MapPerson` object, not the `Person` one.

Your code should be:

```
Person person = MapPerson.get("Eminem");
System.out.println(person.getName() + " " + person.getGender());
```